# How do I check what version of Julia is running my code?

Tags: julia

is there a way to Check what version of Julia is running the code? this matters when you already have more than 1 Julia on your machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To find where is Julia located try:

```
type -a julia
```

On a Windows machine `where julia` will be useful:

```
$ where julia
c:\Julia-1.7.1\bin\julia.exe
```

To find the actual version just do `julia -version`:

```
$ julia -version
julia version 1.7.1
```

When inside Julia there is a special `VERSION` variable of type `VersionNumber`:

```
julia> dump(VERSION)
VersionNumber
  major: UInt32 0x00000001
  minor: UInt32 0x00000007
  patch: UInt32 0x00000001
  prerelease: Tuple{} ()
  build: Tuple{} ()
```

This variable can also be reached from console (Windows version of this code will require `"` instead of `'`:

```
$ julia -e 'println(VERSION)'
1.7.1
```

Finally you might want to check which Julia is actually running your current code:

```
julia> Base.julia_cmd()
`'c:\Julia-1.7.1\bin\julia.exe' -Cnative '-Jc:\Julia-1.7.1\lib\julia\sys.dll' -g1`

julia> Base.julia_cmd()[1]
"c:\\Julia-1.7.1\\bin\\julia.exe"
```

Last but not least, sometimes you will just want to use `versioninfo()`:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.7.1
Commit ac5cc99908 (2021-12-22 19:35 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-12.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
Environment:
  JULIA_DEPOT_PATH = C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.7.1
```

Comment: That's a pretty dizzying array of possibilities. I thought simply `versioninfo()` was the canonical answer.

Comment: I had an idea to put all options in one place :)

Answer (score 9):

The [`VERSION`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/constants/#Base.VERSION) constant gives you the version number.

Comment: is [versioninfo](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.versioninfo) usable?

Comment: Yes, that shows the version number too, but it is like buing a full car when you just need a single spare part.